NASM x64: Floating Point Part Incorrectly Printed as 0.000000
I'm a newbie to assembly and I tried to write an assembly program using NASM on Windows (x64) to extract and print the fractional part of a floating-point number. However, my program prints Floating Point Part: 0.000000 instead of the expected Floating Point Part: 0.500000.
Here is my current code:
section .data
    fmt db "Floating Point Part: %f", 10, 0
    float_value dq 10.5
    result dq 0.0

section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
    ; Function prologue
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32              ; Allocate shadow space

    ; Load floating-point value into the FPU
    fld qword [rel float_value]

    ; Call floatVal function
    call floatVal

    ; Store result from the FPU to memory
    fstp qword [rel result]

    ; Print the result using printf
    lea rcx, [rel fmt]       ; First argument: format string
    lea rdx, [rel result]    ; Second argument: address of result
    movsd xmm0, qword [rdx]  ; Move the double to xmm0 for printf
    call printf

    ; Function epilogue
    add rsp, 32              ; Deallocate shadow space
    mov eax, 0
    pop rbp
    ret

floatVal:
    ; Function prologue
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32              ; Allocate shadow space

    ; Get the integer part
    fld st0                  ; Copy the value to the top of the stack
    frndint                  ; Round to integer
    fsub                     ; Subtract integer part from original value (st0 - st1)

    ; Function epilogue
    add rsp, 32              ; Deallocate shadow space
    pop rbp
    ret

Compilation and Execution Steps:
nasm -f win64 flo.asm -o flo.o
gcc -m64 -o flo flo.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt
.\flo.exe

Expected Output:
Floating Point Part: 0.500000

Actual Output:
Floating Point Part: 0.000000

Environment:

Windows 10 x64
NASM
Mingw-w64

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the floating-point operations are correctly handled.
Checked that the stack is properly aligned and shadow space is allocated.
Attempted to print the entire floating-point value directly to isolate the issue.
Used RIP-relative addressing to ensure correct address handling.

The floating-point operations seem to be executed, but the result is not what I expect. It appears as though the result might be overwritten or not correctly passed to printf.
What exactly do I need to know

Why does the program print 0.000000 instead of the expected fractional part?
Are there any mistakes in the floating-point handling or function calling conventions?
How can I correctly print the fractional part of the floating-point number?

I'm very new to low-level programming and any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
PS:
I found the same problems published before in StackOverflow and I tried to update my code referring to them. They aren't working for me and my apologies for re-posting

Floating point in nasm
Floating Point always returns 0


You might find the guidance given in this answer printf calling convention helpful. Another way to do small amounts of x87 code is in MSVC in legacy x86 32 bit mode where you can combine inline assembler code and C printf with ease. PS Unless  I miscounted I think you are leaving an x87 register with a value still on the stack.  I think you want fsubp st(1),st to avoid problems when it is called several times.

@MartinBrown Thank you for your helpful suggestions and references

According to calling convention, the second argument goes into xmm1 not xmm0. Also it should be duplicated into rdx. "Second argument: address of result" makes no sense as printf does not expect the address of a double. You should do:
lea rcx, [rel fmt]       ; First argument: format string
movsd xmm1, [rel result] ; Move the double to xmm1 for printf
movq rdx, xmm1           ; duplicate second argument as per convention
call printf

Also in 64 bit mode you should generally avoid x87 FPU altogether. Leaf functions do not need to allocate shadow space.

SSE's equivalent for frndint is roundsd, which requires SSE4.  That's not a problem these days, but rounding to nearest integer in a fully-portable x86-64 program using only SSE2 or earlier needs multiple instructions.  (Especially if you don't want to assume the value is small enough to fit in a 64-bit integer for convert to int and back, then you need to add/sub a large constant.)

Also, the explanation for the 0.0 is that variadic functions actually do just look at the integer regs when the access to the arg can't be optimized to e.g. always look at the first variadic arg as a double (in which case it would hopefully use the register).  The value the OP leaves in RDX is a user-space address, so its high 16 bits are all zero, so the exponent field of the double is all zero.  So it's a tiny subnormal integer, and %f rounds it to 0.0.  %g would use scientific notation and show you the tiny non-zero value.

Thank you everyone for your helpful suggestions!
The issue is resolved now. The key was to use xmm1 for the second argument and to avoid using the x87 FPU entirely.

@kavicastelo: The content of XMM1 is irrelevant in practice.  What mattered was the copy of the value in RDX.  (The calling convention requires that RDX matches XMM1 for a variadic FP arg, so Jester's answer is good, but it's not really correct to say that using XMM1 was the key, it's copying to the corresponding GPR which your original code also wasn't doing.)

@PeterCordes: Thank you sir for clarifying my misunderstandings. I'm a newbie to assembly and, however, Jester's answer helped me to step up. I'll try to implement your recommendations and if you could help me find resources to learn more, it would be much appreciated :)

@kavicastelo: there are some good links to official docs and some guides in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info .  As for understanding stuff like only RDX mattering in practice, that comes from understanding the point of the design decision to require that variadic XMM args are mirrored to the integer reg (Jester linked MS docs for those.)  That plus shadow space allows a simple implementation of variadic functions by dumping the integer regs into the shadow space, making a contiguous array of args on the stack.  So obviously that's what MSVC actually does when compiling their library.

Here is the corrected code. Might be helpful for someone :)
section .data
    fmt db "Floating Point Part: %f", 10, 0
    float_value dq 10.5

section .bss
    result resq 1

section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
    ; Function prologue
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    ; Load the floating-point value into xmm0
    movsd xmm0, qword [rel float_value]

    ; Get the fractional part
    movapd xmm1, xmm0        ; Copy the value to xmm1
    roundsd xmm1, xmm0, 0    ; Round to integer in xmm1
    subsd xmm0, xmm1         ; Subtract integer part from xmm0

    ; Store the result
    movsd qword [rel result], xmm0

    ; Prepare arguments for printf
    lea rcx, [rel fmt]       ; First argument: format string
    movsd xmm1, qword [rel result]  ; Move the double to xmm1 for printf
    movq rdx, xmm1           ; Duplicate second argument as per convention
    call printf

    ; Function epilogue
    mov eax, 0
    pop rbp
    ret

Thanks again for all the help! Suggestions are gratefully welcome.
